# Is there an existing form field that allows adding an arbitrary sequence of elements without re-rendering?

Tags: django, django-forms

Well, the title speaks for itself. I'm looking for a Django form field that cleanly replicates this behavior **without** resorting to custom/external Javascript:

Say you have a form for creating an `Item`. An `Item` has, for example, a Title, Description, and Date. You fill those out, and click on, say, "Add another `Item`". Then a new "line" of fields appears, with its own new Title, Description and Date fields under the previous one, and you can fill those out, and so on. When you're done adding "lines", you press send and the POST data contains all the "lines" you filled.

Is there a way to do this without, like I said, resorting to custom Javascript or re-rendering the form? I've checked the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/) but haven't found any, and I know the default admin forms do this, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Your best bet are formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets

Answer (score 0):

Using the comment by @bonidjukic as reference, I've investigated a little and I've come across [this](http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html), which details how to do exactly what I'm looking to achieve. It would seem, however, that using Javascript is inevitable...a shame, but expected.

I will leave the question open for a while just in case someone has a better alternative.